# Different function signature between my project and official reference guide

Tags: android, kotlin

New to Android development here. Why are some function parameters nullable in my project, but not so in the official reference guide? My minimum sdk level is 22

For instance `onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int)` in my case but `onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int)` in the guide and some tutorials I see. It gets annoying when I have to append `!!` each and every time.

Comment: Nothing is optional in both onCreateViewHolder() implementations. Their only difference is that parent: ViewGroup? is nullable but parent: ViewGroup is not.

Comment: sorry, I meant nullable, not optional

Comment: This change happened when the support library upgraded from v7:27.0.2 to v7:27.1.0 about 3 months ago. I remember it because it caused me problems. I guess that this is expected to happen again after upgrades. I always follow the new version.

Comment: Yes I do notice mine is still v7:27.0.2. How can I upgrade it and how can I get notified whenever there is a newer version available?

Comment: Android Studio notifies you if there are new versions. You can do it manually from the menu Help/Check for Updates...

Comment: got it, thanks a lot!

Comment: It's happening because newer version of support lib method is properly annotated as `NonNull`. You might want to read more about [platform types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types) to avoid this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) ...
```

even when Android Studio/IDEA generates `parent: ViewGroup?` (because the parameter isn't annotated rather than annotated `@Nullable`).